# Single Managed Bean for retrieving different types of lists

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

Are there any issues if I use a single ManagedBean for retrieving multiple kinds of list. A `List` of `Integer`(s), a list of `String`(s) or list of `Object`(s) depending on the context. I won't need to retrieve all kinds of list at the same time/same request, So I put each retrieved list to the same field of the managedbean instance.

My bean code is as follows:-

```
@ManagedBean(name="listRetriever")
@RequestScoped
public class ListRetriever {

    private int requestedId;
    private Iterable list;

    public void retrieveIntegersList(){
         ...
         ...
         list = ..;  
    }

    public void retrieveStringsList(){
         ...
         ...
         list = ..;  
    }
```

Although this works perfect & in the EL I'm able to fetch properties & methods related to the corresponding objects in the list, but I just wanted to know if there may be any issues with this ?

Comment: I already use in some situations this approach and from my point of view there is nothing wrong with it. We just have to keep in mind that the bean itself doesn't say much, because it depends on the context it is being used.

Comment: thanks & regarding the `Iterable list` instead of `Iterable<Integer> list` or  `Iterable<String> list`, does that lead to some added costs as the objects of the list would again need to be recasted each time while fetching its properties or methods in the EL ??

Comment: Expression language isn't type safe, meaning no cast is necessary ;), it will access all properties and methods using reflection

Comment: Well, actually EL recognizes certain types. For example the primitives (and their wrappers), `List`, `Map` and `ResourceBundle` have special treatment. All other types are just treated as beans.